# MVC: Complex Array Model Binding Fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm stuck on this one, can someone explain why the lines don't bind??

I've tried submitting with JSON.stringify and all sorts of combinations.

I'm now running it through unit tests and it still isn't binding.

```
var formCollection = new NameValueCollection 
{
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Lines][0][Part]", "ABD33-360-2" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Lines][0][PartDescription]", "CARRIAGE ASSEMBLY (MOVEABLE)" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Lines][0][PartIss]", "C" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Lines][0][Price]", "1060.06" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Lines][0][PriceBreaks]", "null" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Lines][0][Number]", "5" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Lines][0][LeadTime]", "0" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Lines][0][Unit]", "EACH" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Narrative][0]", "a" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][QualityNarrative][]", "a" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][Agent]", "11" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][COSITE]", "0" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][TotalVAT]", "0" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0][VATNo]", "null" },
};

var valueProvider = new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(formCollection, null);
var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(PreDelivery));
var bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext {
    ModelName = "",
    ValueProvider = valueProvider,
    ModelMetadata = metadata
};
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext();
var sut = new DefaultModelBinder();

// act    
PreDelivery PD = (PreDelivery)sut.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("PreDelivery {0}", PD != null));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("PD.PurchaseOrders {0}", PD.PurchaseOrders != null));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("PD.PurchaseOrders[0] {0}", PD.PurchaseOrders[0] != null));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("PD.PurchaseOrders[0].Lines {0}", PD.PurchaseOrders[0].Lines != null));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("PD.PurchaseOrders[0].Lines {0}", PD.PurchaseOrders[0].Lines.Count.ToString()));
```

Class - (heavily simplified for this post):

```
public class Order : IOrder {
        public string Agent { get; set; }

        public string Buyer { get; set; }
        public string Carrier { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string CusSupCode { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CusSupRef { get; set; }
        public string CusSupAddr { get; set; }
        public int iDelAddr { get; set; }
        public string DelAddr { get; set; }
        public string InvAddr { get; set; }
        public eInvoiceType InvoiceType { get; set; }
        public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
        public string[] Narrative { get; set; }
        public string[] QualityNarrative { get; set; }
        public string Release { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }

        public class Line {
            public string CusSupPart { get; set; }
            public decimal DiscountPC { get; set; }
            public string DP { get; set; }
            public bool IsFOC { get; set; }
            public bool IsScheduled { get; set; }
            public string OrderRef { get; set; }
            public int OrderRefLine { get; set; }
            public bool POA { get; set; }
            public string Part { get; set; }
            public string PartDescription { get; set; }
            public string PartIss { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
            public string[] Narrative { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }
            public int LeadTime { get; set; }
            public string Unit { get; set; }
            public DateTime? ReqDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime SchdDate { get; set; }
            public decimal UnitConv { get; set; }   
        }

        public class HistoryEntry {
            public string Narrative { get; set; }
            public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected format for Array binding is `Property[0].Key` but you're using `Property[0][Key]`.

Try this instead:

```
{ "PurchaseOrders[0].Lines[0].Part", "ABD33-360-2" },
{ "PurchaseOrders[0].Lines[0].PartDescription", "CARRIAGE ASSEMBLY (MOVEABLE)" },
{ ... }
```